# Fragment issue , fragment is not compatible

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, animation

I'm following a tutorial on youtbe which is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayKMfVt2Sg4
and i've repeated it many times to make sure i haven't made any error, but for some reason it's not working for me, this is my code for the loginadaater fragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class  LoginAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    int totalTabs;

    public LoginAdapter (FragmentManager fm, Context context, int totalTabs ) {
        super(fm);
        this.context=context;
        this.totalTabs=totalTabs;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return totalTabs;
    }
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        switch (position){
            case 0:
               LoginTabFragment LoginTabFragment=new LoginTabFragment();
                return LoginTabFragment;
            case 1:
                SigninTabFragment SigninTabFragment=new SigninTabFragment();
                return SigninTabFragment;
            default:
                return null;

        }
    }
}
```

and i keep getting the following error:

```
return type android.app.fragment is not compatible with androidx.fragment.app.fragment
```

i've followed everything correctly and got no idea why i get this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using androidx not android. So please,

**Replace:**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

**To:**

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```